# How to make periodical synchronization in this function?

Tags: python, windows, synchronization

I need to make an app that sends its content to another directory so their contents are exactly the same. On top of that I need it to send logs and also I should provide an amount of time when this application makes another synchronization between the folders. Atm it works only once and I got an error message that I need to provide sys.args (path1, path2 etc) once again.

```
from subprocess import call
import sys
import os
import glob
import filecmp
import schedule
import time


def check(path1, path2, path3):
    comp = filecmp.cmp(path1, path2, shallow=True)
    # Comparison of files on two folders, if they aren't the same the replica folder's content is removed and then the
    # content of the source file is copied here.
    if comp is True:
        pass
        print("Content of both folder is the same!", file=open(path3, 'a'))
    else:
        files = glob.glob(path2 + "\\" + '*')
        for f in files:
            os.remove(f)
    print("Files from: " + path1 + " sent to: " + path2, file=open(path3, 'a'))
    try:
        call(["robocopy", path1, path2, "/MIR"])
        print("The content of both libraries is now the same!", file=open(path3, 'a'))
    finally:
        pass


def s(interval):  # s stands for schedule
    schedule.every(int(interval)).minutes.do(check)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


if sys.argv[1] == "-c":
    check(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[5])
    s(sys.argv[4])
# Given are 5 arguments when calling this function via cmd: 1 -c for calling it, 2 is path/to/source, 3 path/to/replica
# 4 - time how often this app should run once again(in minutes) and 5 is the path where log file is going to be placed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason this is working once, is because you are calling the `check` function, outside of the scheduler:

> `check(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[5])`

As the error message should indicate, you haven't passed any argument to the function that is called by the scheduler. To do so, according to [the documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job), you can simply pass the required argument to the `do` function, which will forward them to your function. In your case, that would look like

```py
def s(interval, path1, path2, path3):  # s stands for schedule
    schedule.every(int(interval)).minutes.do(check, path1=path1, path2=path2, path3=path3)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if sys.argv[1] == "-c":
    check(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[5])
    s(sys.argv[4], path1=sys.argv[2], path2=sys.argv[3], path3=sys.argv[5])
```

for instance.

Comment: Thanks that's working! However from time to time I got this error
"PermissionError: [WinError 5]"Access Denied to one of dirs in the path2, do you know what might be the reason for it?

Comment: Hmm that seems to be a different and probably unrelated error. I would say, maybe the dir is being used by another programme, or something like that? Make sure to run your python script as administrator I guess

Comment: Yee I've done it, but it's something with the path itself. Because when during this instance I remove the subfolder manually another instance works well too

Comment: Since this is un unrelated issue, I think you can ask another question regarding your new issue! :)